# Maximize summation with variable in the upper limit

Tags: optimization, summation

Let $x \in \{ 0, 1, \ldots, N \}$, I need to find

$$\mathrm{argmax}_{x} \sum_{n=0}^{N-x} f_{n}(x)$$ where $f_{n}(x)$ is such that $$f_{n}(x+1) > f_{n}(x)$$ $$f_{n+1}(x) < f_{n}(x).$$

Note that $x$ appears both in the upper limit of the summation (increasing $x$ implies summing up less terms) and in the functions $f_{n}(x)$ (increasing $x$ implies summing up larger terms).

Is there a general approach to solve this problem? I suppose that solving $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \sum_{n=0}^{N-x} f_{n}(x) = 0$ does not make sense in this case since the function is not continuous in $x$.